# I am trying to query two tables in my laravel database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to query two tables in a database but its returning this error.
I am trying to implement a search through multiple tables. The project is an online store with 3 distinctive tables, Products, Categories and Brands. I can only search through the Products table but can't seem to get the same search field from my blade file to search either the categories or the brands and return results of the associated products.

```
QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `categories` inner join `products` on `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` where `name` LIKE %Television% and `status` = 1)
```

My Search function

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request) {
        $product = $request->input('product');

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $productsAll = Category::query()->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
                                    ->where('status', 1)->get();


        $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / ".$product;

        return view('pages.results')->with(compact('categories','productsAll','product','breadcrumb'));

    }
```

My Category Model

```
class Category extends Model implements Searchable
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','id');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```

My Products Model

```
class Product extends Model implements Searchable
{

    public function category() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'id') ;
    }

    public function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product','id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have status column in more than one table.
Change this

```
->where('status', 1)->get();
```

to this

```
->where('products.status', 1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by modifying my search function as follows.

```
public function searchProducts(Request $request) {
        $product = $request->input('product');

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $productsAll = Category::query()->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                                    ->where('categories.name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
                                    ->orWhere('products.product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$product}%")
                                    ->where('products.status', 1)->get();


        $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / ".$product;

        return view('pages.results')->with(compact('categories','productsAll','product','breadcrumb'));

    }
```